# Step Indicator CSS

Tags: css, sass

i am trying to mimic this step indicator, but I have just begun to learn SASS, and by no means a pro with CSS in general.

I am trying to achieve this:
[image]

but have this so far:
[image]

CodePen: https://codepen.io/tarnn/pen/XEPdMP
`

```
.progressbar li.completed:before {
        content: '';
        background: url("/assets/icons/check.svg") 0 3px no-repeat;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-color: #ebeae8;
    }`
```

Getting pretty close, but I realized there are a few issues I do not know how to solve as of yet, and was hoping for a push in the right direction.

What the original has, that I am struggling with:

1. Font size increases per step, 1-2-3-4 etc.
2. Line in between steps has a small margin/space on both ends
3. Font below it does not fit perfect and nor is it centered correctly.

** Text is correct in mine, and wrong in the original **

Each step adds a class:

Active: the current with the blue circle and number is the active class.
Completed: Adds gray checkbox, i'm using an SVG.
Inactive: Normal white BG with text.

Comment: Please add the relevant bits of code to your question in the form of a [mcve] - if the codepen gets deleted, the question itself becomes incomplete (and useless) thus making it impossible to answer.  Also, I'd suggest editing your title to be more descriptive of your issue (right now is so generic it could mean anything) - this makes it easier for future users to find the right question/answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some changes that might help, with an updated CodePen below (with additional comments in the SCSS):

- Use SASS variables for the circle sizes and borders, and for the gap between the lines and the circles:

  `$circleSize: 50px;
   $circleBorderWidth: 5px;
   $lineOffset: 10px;`

  This makes it easier to calculate the line widths, positions, and line-height. For example:

  `.progressbar li:after {
      width: calc(100% - #{($circleSize + $circleBorderWidth * 2 + $lineOffset * 2)});
   }`
- Add a white border to the non-active items so they match the size of your `active` item - this way the gap between the lines and the circles can be uniform.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RMYRPp

Edit: updated CodePen to fix circle sizes

Comment: Thank you very much dude, never tried calc before, steering me in the right direction. Very appreciative of the comments as well.